# How to delete rows with rowspan jquery

Tags: jquery, row, html-table

```
<table id="personal" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="remove">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="remove">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="remove">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$('#personal tr .remove').click(function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
})
```

I want to remove 2 rows that effected by rowspan. It is possible? If yes how? Now it only remove one row.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/awanan/j3fNK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way:

```
$('#personal tr .remove').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().remove();
   $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `$(this).parent().next().remove();` before `$(this).parent().remove();`